# counter for the number of responses for specific paramater of a hashmap JAVA enum

Tags: java

```
public enum yes {
TEACHER,STUDENT
}




public class SCHOOL {
String name = null;
String surname = null;
int id = 0;
yes type = null;


    public SCHOOL(String name,String surname,int id,yes type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    }



    HashMap<String,SCHOOL>  persons = new HashMap<String,SCHOOL>();
}
```

needed help in making counter for how many people selected student or professional in the hashmap, is this possible to do in 1 counter or do you have to do it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your hashmap values via a Java 8+ Stream and use the `count()` method to get the number of elements that match a `filter` predicate.

Also, you don't have a `yes` enum element called `PROFESSIONAL`, so I assumed you will add it to your enum definition.

```java
  int studentsOrProfessionals = persons.values().stream()
    .filter(x -> List.of(yes.TEACHER, yes.PROFESSIONAL).contains(x.getType()))
    .distinct()
    .count();
```

Comment: what does the x represent and could you possibly also show me the solution for just one enum

Comment: Please read up on [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to understand what the `x` means. For one `yes` value, use `x  -> yes.TEACHER.equals(x.getType())`.

Comment: say if the question was responses for only one enum, can you use an easier method to achieve this

Comment: This is the easier method. Otherwise you'll be writing a lot of boilerplate code to do the exact same thing. Learn about Java streams [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm).